# rspec error(michael hartl )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is the error I am getting in using bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb.

I have included gem test-unit.

Please help I am completely new to rails.

```
/home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <module:FixtureSupport>': private method `fixture_path' called for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x005584a641b380> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  fixture_path=
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:17:in `class_eval'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:17:in `block in <module:FixtureSupport>'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/concern.rb:114:in `class_eval'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/concern.rb:114:in `append_features'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:791:in `include'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:791:in `safe_include'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:785:in `block in configure_group'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:783:in `each'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:783:in `configure_group'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/world.rb:47:in `configure_group'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:290:in `set_it_up'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:241:in `subclass'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in `describe'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
from /home/sarfraz/Desktop/Rails Apps/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: can you post the content of the failing spec you're running, along with your Gemfile?

Comment: If you're running the tests with `rspec`, why are you also including `test-unit` (different testing framework)? Can you post your `Gemfile` and `spec/spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: this is the new error:/home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/assertions (LoadError)

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue after upgrading my project to Ruby 2.3.1 from Ruby 2.1 

Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to upgrade `rspec-rails`. For example you can use `gem 'rspec-rails', '~>2.13'` in your Gemfile and do `bundle update rspec-rails` from a terminal. It setups 2.99.x for you. This version is workable with at least ruby 2.3.4 and provides backward compatibility.